# Read physical file, retain largest amount and delete all others with same search argument

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I'm doing a program that reads all records in physical file using logical file(transaction code, transaction date and transaction amount), checks whether there are 2 or more records with same trans code and trans date, and determine what's the largest amount. I'm supposed to retain the record with the largest amount and delete(delete flag='D') others (with same trans code and trans date).

How will I know what's the record with the largest amount?
I mean, if there are 1000 records and I found 7 identical trans code and trans date, if the largest amount is record 7th, how do I delete records 1 to 6 when after reading the file, file pointer goes to the next record,right?

I do apologize if this comes as confusing. This is confusing me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use embedded SQL for something like this. Without knowing the format of your table, you could use aggregation to find the records to update, something like this:

```
exec sql
  update table a
    set deletecode = 'D'
    where amount <> (select max(amount) from table
                     where trancd = a.trancd);
```

This works by finding the `max(amount)` for rows with the same `trancd` as the one being updated. If the amount on the row being updated is different from the `max(amount)` for that `trancd`, then go ahead and update the `deletecode`, otherwise do not update it. There is no need to check whether there are two or more records since if there is only one record, the `max(amount)` will be the same as the `amount` field on the transaction to be updated.